# Slicing Python Lists by Number

Tags: python

I am new to Python, is there any best way to resolve below issue list slicing

I have main list called

```
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

I would like to slice above list divide 12 and expecting to have the following output:

```
new_result = {
    'One' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    'Two' : [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    'Three' : [25, 26]
}
```

Comment: Check the [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of the `itertools` module documentation, specifically the `grouper` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you split a list into evenly-sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
          14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]

chunk_size = 12

splitted_result = [result[x:x+chunk_size]
                   for x in range(0, len(result), chunk_size)]

for chunk in splitted_result:
    print(chunk)
```

Result:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[25, 26]
```

Into the last for loop you can create the object with the correct keys.

The script logic is simple:
The `range` function takes three arguments:

- start (0)
- stop (length of the list)
- step (increment between each returned value)

In your case you will have:
`range(0, len(result), chunk_size)=[0,12,24]`
and you just have to split the initial list in chunks that goes from:

`result[0:0+12]`
`result[12:12+12]`
`result[24:24+12]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
new_list = [result[n-1:n+11] for n in result[::12]]

new_result = {}
for n in range(1,len(new_list)+1):
    new_result[n] = new_list[n-1]
new_result

{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 2: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
 3: [25, 26]}
```

The `new_list` is just the list with the sliced lists. Then, I convert it into a dictionary called `new_result`, starting from '1' onwards